# Bigquery fetch records based on their updation date

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a following data :

```
Row Column 1    Column 2    batch_date
1   Account 1   zipcode 1   11/28/2020
2   Account 1   zipcode 1   11/29/2020
3   Account 1   zipcode 1   11/30/2020
4   Account 1   zipcode 2   12/1/2020
5   Account 1   zipcode 2   12/2/2020
6   Account 1   zipcode 2   12/3/2020
7   Account 1   zipcode 2   12/4/2020
8   Account 1   zipcode 2   12/5/2020
9   Account 1   zipcode 2   12/6/2020
10  Account 1   zipcode 2   12/7/2020
11  Account 1   zipcode 2   12/8/2020
12  Account 1   zipcode 2   12/9/2020
13  Account 1   zipcode 2   12/10/2020
14  Account 1   zipcode 3   12/11/2020
15  Account 1   zipcode 3   12/12/2020
```

I would like to fetch data for this account for dates when the column2 (zipcode) has been changed.

Output should be like below:

```
Row Column 1    Column 2    batch_date
1   Account 1   zipcode 1   11/28/2020
2   Account 1   zipcode 2   12/1/2020
3   Account 1   zipcode 3   12/11/2020
```

How can we do it in bigquery ?

I have already tried FIRST_VALUE() function but the query is resulting into "resources issue".
I also tried self join but that is not giving the desired output.
Can anybody help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardsql
select * except(changed) from (
  select *, column_2 != ifnull(lag(column_2) over win, '') changed
  from `project.dataset.table`
  window win as (partition by column_1 order by parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', batch_date) asc)
)
where changed
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Note: above code assumes your `batch_date` column is of STRING data type - thus use of `parse_date` function. If this column is of `DATE` data type - you don't need this function and can use just `batch_date` instead of `parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', batch_date)`

Comment: did you have chance to try?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with the help of [navigation functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#first_value) in BigQuery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Row, c1, c2, FIRST_VALUE(batch_date) 
OVER (PARTITION BY c2 ORDER BY batch_date ASC) AS batch_date
FROM table;
```

I replaced "Column 1" with "c1", "Column 2" with "c2" for purpose of the example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried Navigation functions but on my dataset it is resulting into error "Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory.".